# Top of Element Relative to Bottom of Parent

Tags: html, css, web, position

I have two `div`s: one on top of another (I'll call the top one `topDiv` and the bottom one `bottomDiv`), they each have a `width` of 100%. They are inside another `div` called `parent`. `parent` acts as a dummy/container, its main purpose is to aid in positioning of `topDiv` and `bottomDiv`. Each of these `div`s use absolute positioning. `bottom` has a fixed height, so I have the `bottom` css property of `topDiv` set to this height. However, I do not have a `top` css property for `bottomDiv`, as I assumed it would be directly under `topDiv`, but it isn't.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
  border-color: green;
}
#parent > div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 2em;
  padding: 0.1em;
}
#top {
  border-color: red;
  border-style: dashed;
}
#bottom {
  height: 2.25em;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="top">This should be on top.</div>
  <div id="bottom">On the bottom is where I should be.</div>
</div>
```

All of the direction properties (`top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`) are measured from the direction they name (e.g. `top` is measured from the top, so if something like `5em` is specified, then the element is placed 5em away from the top of its container), but is there a way to reverse the effect? For instance, specifying an amount for `right` that would cause the element to be placed the specified amount away from the *left* of its container rather than its *right*.

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: Please clarify your **specific problem** or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Why do absolute elements stack up on each other instead of stacking one after the other?](/q/20718577/90527)", "[Css Sibling Absolute Positioning](/q/10624771/90527)", "[Position bottom edge of element inside container](/q/11148836/90527)"

Answer (score 3):

Since the `top` property defines the distance from the parents `top`, then using `top:100%`, which means *"the distance from parent's `top` is equal to parent's `height`"*, you set your elements top to it's parents bottom.

Now, if you want to get your element's top, for example, 5px from the parents bottom, you can use `calc`

```
.bottomDiv {
  top:calc(100% + 5px);
}
```